# Microsoft Graph - Office 365 - restrict access to particular fields?

Tags: azure, graph, office365

I have searched for information on whether it's possible to restrict Graph API access to particular fields/columns (i.e. date time received, last modified, sender, etc.) for e-mails in Office 365 by setting up permissions in Azure - but I can't find anything on this topic.

The goal here would be to prevent anyone from pulling back the restricted fields when they make an API call.

Anyone know whether this is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

There is no permission at the field level.

The detailed of perms scope available is mentioned below :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions

If you would like to restrict further, you could make use of the delegated permission. In this case, you can restrict access to the ones for which user have access to.